# How to determine the maximum area of a rectangle in a coordinate system with a function?

Tags: calculus, optimization, rectangles

I am currently struggling with a math problem and was wondering if someone could help me out. The problem is as follows:

In a coordinate system, a rectangle is drawn with one corner at the origin, one corner on the positive $x$-axis, one corner on the positive $y$-axis, and one corner on the graph of the function $f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-5 x}$.

I need to determine the largest possible area that such a rectangle can have. I have tried to solve it using basic calculus, but I am not getting the correct answer. Could someone provide me with some guidance or a step-by-step solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please show your attempt. You might be closer than you think.

Comment: @DavidK $\frac{d}{dx} e^{-5x}=-5e^{-5x},\  \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} e^{-5x}=25e^{-5x}$. Then we want too find when the graph interssects with the x-axis so that we can choose a y-value to give us our max, since the area is defined by the region occupied within the boundary of the rectangle, and the boundaries are among others the origin and the y-axis.